# Get User Location on Map won't run unless you update Google Play Services

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api-3, android-emulator

Get User Location on Map won't run unless you update Google Play Services

[Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teekS.png)

[image]

when i click the "UPDATE" Button it gives me this Error in the Logcat

```
02-24 15:16:43.969 3958-3958/ahmed_smae.getuserlocationonmap E/DeferredLifecycleHelper: Failed to start resolution intent                             
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms&pcampaignid=gcore_11910000--ahmed_smae.getuserlocationonmap-1 flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1937)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1616)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzf.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Any Help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue! You just have to open the AVD Manager, create a new device but take care that you choose one which has the Play Store logo there. Run your app with the new device, when you click on update then it will bring you to play store where you can update your google play services!

Comment: You are Right. I installed Nexus 5 with Google Play. and it works fine. Thank You